# How do I call upon my settings (array) listed in html using prototype in my javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks

I'm relatively new to javascript development and have tried to construct my own framework. I've been trying to convert my standard javascript functions to a framework. However I've been stuck at a relatively simple (I think), but nowhere explained issue.

In my HTML I call on the settings I want to use in my JavaScript (the user has to be able to edit them in html, not in js as it will be minified).

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var settings = {authenticFilter: 'on', 
            randomizeHeaders: {state: 'on', topHeader: 'h1', bottomHeader: 'h2'},
         };
            var papery = new Papery(settings);
        });
    </script>
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to use the settings I have given to my framework in the javascript file.

I know I can call upon `this.settings = settings;` in my javascript file, but in an if statement below, I want make use of specific settings in the given settings. However this option and several other ways I've tried to use the settings won't work. Can I even use the settings I give to the prototype from my html in an array?

```
var Papery = function (settings) {

Papery.authenticFilter = function() { 
            if (Papery.authenticFilter == 'on'){
                $("img").addClass("authenticFilter");
                $(".authenticFilter").css({"filter": "sepia(80%) grayscale(1) contrast(1) opacity(0.7)", "-webkit-filter": "sepia(80%) contrast(1) opacity(0.7)"});
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: its not Papery.authenticFilter but rather settings.authenticFilter

Comment: Ok that was the worst mistake I've made yet. Thanks! If you put it up as an answer I'll verify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Papery.authenticFilter` instead of `settings.authenticFilter`. Keep in mind that in usual libraries, a bunch of default settings are set in initialization in case they are not defined on the settings passed on the constructor.